# Do mobile web browsers and mobile web apps share the same localStorage

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, local-storage, web

I am working on a site for mobile devices.  The site is available through normal web browsers and also through an app which is just a browser shell and brings up the mobile site.  In our efforts to speed up the loading of the site in mobile we have reduced requsts, made use of data uris, etc.  Recently we have started using localStorage to save styles and JavaScript data to the device.

Why you may ask?
In our testing, mobile browsers maintain their cache throughout their session and when the browser is closed and re-opened.  The app maintains its cache as long as it is being used, but when it is closed and re-opened it re-requests everything, thus slowing down that initial load.

The problem is, we have styles and JavaScript that are specific for if you are in the browser or in the app for a few small things.  We've seen a few things break around these subtle differences and my best theory is that localStorage is shared between the browser and the app.  And a user that uses both the site and the app may have problems if the localStorage was set by one and needs something else for the other.

I can't find any documentation that confirms this theory or not, and short of creating an app just to test this I figured I'd ask if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: You should state what mobile OS are you referring to, because different OSes could show different behaviors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH6-SW1)...

> Like cookies, storage objects are a shared resource common to web
>   content served from the same domain. **All pages from the same domain
>   share the same local storage object**. Frames and inline frames whose
>   contents are from the same origin also share the same session storage
>   object because they descend from the same window.
>
> Because the storage resource is shared, scripts running in multiple
>   page contexts can potentially modify the data stored in a storage
>   object that is actively being scrutinized or modified by a script
>   running on a different page. If your scripts do not notice these
>   changes, you may not get the results you expect.

If you are populating your app with data from the same place as the web app, I would suspect there are some keys being modified by the other one.  I know that using sessionStorage.clear() will wipe out keys if the web app and offline app load data from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

As Chiguireitor said it depends on what mobile OS the user is using, but in my experience iOS 4 & 5 share the same localStorage whether you're accessing the mobile app through the Safari browser or as a homescreen web app. And of course if you package it with something like Phonegap it acts as its own app therefore its localStorage is not shared.